# Borrow and return methods in Library management system

Tags: java, methods

I have a simple question. I have two methods: Return and Borrow. Whenever I try

to borrow It keeps on returning true, and whenever I try to return it always return false.

When I was trying to debug the code, it seems that the program goes through the true and then

to false immediately.

Here is the borrow method:

```
public boolean Borrow (String TitleOrAuthor,int id){
  int count = 0;
  int b1 = 0;
  int BookCount [] = new int [b1];
  for (int i=0;i<Bcount;i++){
     if(Booklist[i].getTitle().equals(TitleOrAuthor)){
        for(int j=0;j<b1;j++){
           BookCount = Booklist[i].getCopies();
           BookCount [j] = id;
           b1++;
        }
        return true;
     }
     else
        return false;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<Ucount;i++){
     if (users[i].getID()==id){
        if (users[i].getOccupation()=='S'){
           count = users[i].getNumBorrowed();
           if (count<=3)
              count++;
           return true;
        }
        else if (count>3)
           return false;

        if (users[i].getOccupation()=='P'){
           count = users[i].getNumBorrowed();
           if (count<=5)
              count++;
           return true;
        }
        else if (count>5)
           return false;
     } 
  }
  return false;
 }
```

And this is the return method:

```
   public boolean Return (String TitleOrAuthor, int id){
  int count = 0;
  int b1 =0;
  int BookCount [] = new int [b1];
  for (int i=0;i<Bcount;i++){
     if(Booklist[i].getTitle().equals(TitleOrAuthor))
        for(int j=0;j<b1;j++){
           BookCount = Booklist[i].getCopies();
           BookCount[j] = --id;
           b1--;
           if(Booklist[i].getTitle()!=TitleOrAuthor){
              return false;
           }
        }
  }
  for (int i=0;i<Ucount;i++){
     if (users[i].getID()==id){
        if(users[i].getNumBorrowed()>0)
           count = users[i].getNumBorrowed();
        count--;
        if(users[i].getNumBorrowed()==0){
           return false;
        }
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

*Note: The BookCount array saves the id of the user when the user borrows.

Thank you.

**Edit: In the main here's the calling method:Borrow:

```
private void BorrowBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {    
  int a = Integer.parseInt(LogInField.getText());
  L1.Borrow (OptionField.getText(),a);
  if (L1.Borrow (OptionField.getText(),a)==true){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The book was borrowed succesfully");
  }
  else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You reached the maximum number");
  }
}
```

Return:

```
private void ReturnBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  int a = Integer.parseInt(LogInField.getText());
  L1.Return (OptionField.getText(),a);
  if (L1.Return (OptionField.getText(),a)==true){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The book was returned succesfully");
  }
  else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot return a book you did not borrow");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to edit your question to say what returned boolean should mean.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < b1; j++) { b1++; }` - why are you increasing the upper bound during iteration?

Comment: if `Booklist[0].getTitle().equals(TitleOrAuthor)` is false, than your borrow method will return false every time.  If it is true, it will return true every time.

Comment: normally, when you step through a debugger, you will also be able to see what the values in memory are.  you should use those features to see the content of variables including but not limited to `Booklist` and `TitleOrAuthor`,

Comment: It's because b1 is 0. Whenever there is an ID saved in the array, b1 will increase, but that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, some of them already being mentioned in the comments, e.g.

- In `Borrow` `b1` is always 0 so the loop `for(int j = 0; j < b1; j++) {}` will never run
- In `Borrow` you don't update the burrow count for the users, so `users[i].getNumBorrowed()` would always return 0
- if you stick to the naming conventions (e.g. `titleOrAuthor` instead of `TitleOrAuthor`) it might be easier to distinguish between classes and variables as well as for others to understand your code and provide help
- In `Borrow` assuming b1 was greater than 0, you'd loop over the books and if the title would match, you'd set all copies to the same id, that seems to be a bug
- The first parameter to `Borrow` (again the convention says it should be `borrow()` instead) is called `TitleOrAuthor` but you only check the title, so when the author is provided there's no match
- In `Return` you also have the `b1 = 0` and `for(int j = 0; j < b1; j++) {}` problem
- In `Return` you decrease the loop variable's upper bound `b1` so you'll end the loop earlier than probably assumed (provided the problem above was solved)
- In `Return` you decrease `id` in every iteration of the loop which doesn't fit the same id being used in  `Borrow` and still might be a bug
- In `Return` you also decrease the local variable `count` which will be lost when the method has finished

Comment: Well, I'm increasing count which holds the value of users[i].getNumBorrowed() so I'm not sure why it would't update the value.

Comment: @Boshokai you're increasing a _local_ primitive variable that is removed at the end of the method, so that increase is lost.

Comment: I see, so that's the reason why it returns false each and every time. Thank you.

Comment: @Boshokai yes, that's one of the problems and maybe the most immediate one. That should have turned up during debugging though since `count` would always have been 0, even if you'd called those methods multiple times.